# Convert a 1D array to a 2D array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to convert a 1-dimensional array into a 2-dimensional array by specifying the number of columns in the 2D array. Something that would work like this:

```
> import numpy as np
> A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
> B = vec2matrix(A,ncol=2)
> B
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Does numpy have a function that works like my made-up function "vec2matrix"? (I understand that you can index a 1D array like a 2D array, but that isn't an option in the code I have - I need to make this conversion.)

Answer (score 284, accepted):

You want to [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the array.

```
B = np.reshape(A, (-1, 2))
```

where `-1` infers the size of the new dimension from the size of the input array.

Answer (score 55):

You have two options:

- If you no longer want the original shape, the easiest is just to assign a new shape to the array

  ```
  a.shape = (a.size//ncols, ncols)
  ```

  You can switch the `a.size//ncols` by `-1` to compute the proper shape automatically. Make sure that `a.shape[0]*a.shape[1]=a.size`, else you'll run into some problem.
- You can get a new array with the `np.reshape` function, that works mostly like the version presented above

  ```
  new = np.reshape(a, (-1, ncols))
  ```

  When it's possible, `new` will be just a view of the initial array `a`, meaning that the data are shared. In some cases, though, `new` array will be acopy instead. Note that `np.reshape` also accepts an optional keyword `order` that lets you switch from row-major C order to column-major Fortran order. `np.reshape` is the function version of the `a.reshape` method.

If you can't respect the requirement `a.shape[0]*a.shape[1]=a.size`, you're stuck with having to create a new array. You can use the `np.resize` function and mixing it with `np.reshape`, such as

```
>>> a =np.arange(9)
>>> np.resize(a, 10).reshape(5,2)
```

Answer (score 15):

Try something like:

```
B = np.reshape(A,(-1,ncols))
```

You'll need to make sure that you can divide the number of elements in your array by `ncols` though. You can also play with the order in which the numbers are pulled into `B` using the `order` keyword.

Answer (score 14):

If your sole purpose is to convert a 1d array X to a 2d array just do:

```
X = np.reshape(X,(1, X.size))
```

Answer (score 9):

convert a 1-dimensional array into a 2-dimensional array by adding new axis.

```
a=np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60])

b=a[:,np.newaxis]--it will convert it to two dimension.
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple way as well, we can use the reshape function in a different way:

```
A_reshape = A.reshape(No_of_rows, No_of_columns)
```

Comment: `A = A.reshape(A.shape[0], 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use`flatten()` from the numpy package.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
a_flat = a.flatten()
print(f"original array: {a} \nflattened array = {a_flat}")
```

Output:

```
original array: [[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]] 
flattened array = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'flatten'`

Comment: Could you share your code? Because the numpy sure does have `flatten` method:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Answer (score 0):

```
some_array.shape = (1,)+some_array.shape
```

or get a new one

```
another_array = numpy.reshape(some_array, (1,)+some_array.shape)
```

This will make dimensions +1, equals to adding a bracket on the outermost

Answer (score -1):

Change 1D array into 2D array without using Numpy.

```
l = [i for i in range(1,21)]
part = 3
new = []
start, end = 0, part


while end <= len(l):
    temp = []
    for i in range(start, end):
        temp.append(l[i])
    new.append(temp)
    start += part
    end += part
print("new values:  ", new)


# for uneven cases
temp = []
while start < len(l):
    temp.append(l[start])
    start += 1
    new.append(temp)
print("new values for uneven cases:   ", new)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
array = np.arange(8) 
print("Original array : \n", array)
array = np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4)
print("New array : \n", array)
```

Comment: It's better that you include some explanation along with code.

Comment: Can you explain how your answer now is different from the previous and also the other answers above, that also uses np.reshape?