# Making an image from pixel data

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have a data set of 1200×256. Where 1200 is the time over an hour in 3 seconds interval, and the 256 is for the 256 pixels. I would like to create something like what's below, where the x-axis is time, the y-axis is the pixel. Below is a sample data for the 1st second of my whole data set.

```
data[0]
Out[90]: 
array([ 3967.625 ,  4059.875 ,  4160.625 ,  4253.5625,  4348.75  ,
        4440.    ,  4487.625 ,  4511.1875,  4522.    ,  4546.5625,
        4570.125 ,  4583.3125,  4615.125 ,  4632.4375,  4608.6875,
        4632.    ,  4648.25  ,  4654.    ,  4657.1875,  4661.625 ,
        4664.1875,  4743.4375,  5059.0625,  4708.375 ,  4692.9375,
        4703.625 ,  4704.5   ,  4725.4375,  4736.3125,  4730.625 ,
        4733.5   ,  4743.5625,  4749.    ,  4749.1875,  4733.9375,
        4753.8125,  4769.1875,  4782.3125,  4788.125 ,  4796.125 ,
        4787.375 ,  4769.4375,  4786.3125,  4754.6875,  4751.875 ,
        4757.3125,  4757.8125,  4744.6875,  4737.375 ,  4730.0625,
        4716.3125,  4696.625 ,  4692.6875,  4682.4375,  4676.125 ,
        4673.9375,  4642.4375,  4667.6875,  4655.25  ,  4638.5625,
        4631.875 ,  4641.25  ,  4622.    ,  4622.3125,  4584.9375,
        4609.875 ,  4592.5625,  4595.4375,  4585.75  ,  4574.9375,
        4563.9375,  4576.6875,  4558.625 ,  4572.9375,  4563.8125,
        4553.8125,  4562.25  ,  4577.9375,  4543.4375,  4540.8125,
        4536.4375,  4527.    ,  4541.375 ,  4531.25  ,  4532.8125,
        4524.8125,  4520.625 ,  4494.25  ,  4508.5625,  4516.8125,
        4488.9375,  4493.625 ,  4480.4375,  4477.8125,  4487.1875,
        4485.25  ,  4497.125 ,  4500.4375,  4496.125 ,  4508.75  ,
        4500.625 ,  4501.8125,  4501.25  ,  4508.5625,  4509.6875,
        4511.    ,  4505.4375,  4513.9375,  4523.75  ,  4517.125 ,
        4536.125 ,  4509.25  ,  4508.    ,  4522.5625,  4508.1875,
        4512.1875,  4519.625 ,  4502.    ,  4509.5   ,  4530.3125,
        4533.5   ,  4574.3125,  4566.0625,  4584.25  ,  4585.375 ,
        4597.875 ,  4589.0625,  4593.3125,  4594.25  ,  4586.375 ,
        4578.875 ,  4575.4375,  4567.5   ,  4555.9375,  4572.3125,
        4566.9375,  4576.1875,  4581.125 ,  4580.9375,  4587.    ,
        4589.3125,  4601.1875,  4610.1875,  4609.875 ,  4620.375 ,
        4640.5   ,  4642.125 ,  4652.375 ,  4658.9375,  4680.    ,
        4711.5625,  4714.    ,  4726.    ,  4734.75  ,  4727.875 ,
        4748.    ,  4746.375 ,  4776.3125,  4774.125 ,  4786.6875,
        4822.8125,  4824.625 ,  4827.375 ,  4869.3125,  4884.375 ,
        4905.4375,  4921.125 ,  4933.0625,  4977.3125,  4993.625 ,
        5006.375 ,  5053.3125,  5044.25  ,  5068.5625,  5093.9375,
        5110.25  ,  5137.8125,  5160.8125,  5198.0625,  5198.75  ,
        5227.125 ,  5236.    ,  5242.625 ,  5264.4375,  5308.    ,
        5310.3125,  5365.875 ,  5388.9375,  5393.4375,  5443.6875,
        5478.25  ,  5475.0625,  5492.125 ,  5535.875 ,  5614.3125,
        5664.875 ,  5704.8125,  5761.25  ,  5804.8125,  5839.25  ,
        5898.0625,  5953.6875,  5969.8125,  6020.6875,  6069.75  ,
        6117.8125,  6164.5625,  6203.375 ,  6243.375 ,  6295.1875,
        6325.0625,  6376.6875,  6434.6875,  6485.5   ,  6529.75  ,
        6599.4375,  6647.8125,  6692.8125,  6759.5   ,  6778.5625,
        6828.75  ,  6825.5625,  6817.625 ,  6754.875 ,  6803.9375,
        6811.625 ,  6843.875 ,  6864.0625,  6968.875 ,  7124.8125,
        7228.3125,  7341.375 ,  7523.0625,  7592.375 ,  7602.8125,
        7730.125 ,  7971.9375,  8211.0625,  8454.125 ,  8774.1875,
        9029.625 ,  9279.125 ,  9811.9375, 10612.4375, 11200.4375,
       11083.75  , 10672.4375, 10194.6875, 10232.75  , 10665.25  ,
       10383.5   , 10441.6875, 10118.3125,  7325.125 ,  5216.5   ,
        4201.    ])
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly. I just ran the answers on there, and I got a straight line down the center of the figure.

Comment: It seems you also need to actually make your array two-dimensional. Use `reshape` for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575421/convert-a-1d-array-to-a-2d-array-in-numpy