# I want to get the list of python in the below format

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this

```
list=['a, b, c, d', 'e, f, g, h','i, j, k, l']
```

But i want to have a list like below way

```
target_list=[
              ['a','b','c','d']
              ['e','f','g','h']
              ['i','j','k','l']
           ]
```

Please help me to solve this. I am new into python.

Comment: Do you want to split it to 3 or just have fixed-sized chunks? In any case - there are already answers here to help you.

Comment: ``[l.split(",") for l in list]`` ?

Comment: Dupe target looks incorrect, the question here requires a string split on contents.

Comment: Hi @ReutSharabani, its not the fixed size , size can be more than 3 based on the list size.

Comment: this might do the job, ``[list(map(str.strip, l.split(','))) for l in list_]``

Comment: If you are not against using numpy. Try numpy.reshape()
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575421/convert-a-1d-array-to-a-2d-array-in-numpy

Answer (score 1):

Based on the mentioned example, the length of your list is 3.

```
list[0] = 'a, b, c, d'
list[1] = 'e, f, g, h'
list[2] = 'i, j, k, l'
```

Refer to below code to get the desired target list:

```
list=['a, b, c, d','e, f, g, h','i, j, k, l']
#isalpha() method is used to catch only alphabet and omits spaces and commas
target_list = [[i for i in item if i.isalpha()] for item in list]
print(target_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']
target_list=[]
a=list[0:4]
b=list[4:8]
c=list[8:] 
target_list.append(a)
target_list.append(b)
target_list.append(c)
print(target_list)
```

Comment: Your starting list is not the same as the list in the question...

Comment: Also quality answers generally benefit from an explanation that can help future visitors apply your insight to their own code, increasing long term value and ears of understanding.