# Faster way to move data from a vector to a 2d array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

This is my current code:

```
#move data from vector, A, into 2D array, H
    for i in range(0,nlat):
        jmin = nheader+1+i*nlon
        jmax = nheader+(i+1)*nlon
        A = A[jmin:jmax+1]
        H[i] = A
        A = np.array(Alist)
```

I have a very long vector, and I am taking certain data from it and putting it into a 2D array of dimension nlat x nlon. This setup works but it is very time consuming. Any suggestion of how to speed it up or rewrite it so it doesn't take as long would be very helpful.

Comment: `np.reshape(A, (nlat, nlon))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a 1D array to a 2D array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575421/convert-a-1d-array-to-a-2d-array-in-numpy)

Comment: Not really, because len(A) != nlat*nlon. It won't correctly translate that way. If you can tell by the code, I am taking, say, A[5:10] and putting that in H[0], then A[6:11] and putting that in H[1] and so on. This takes a while, but unfortunately reshaping doesn't do what I need it to.

Comment: What is `nlat` and `nlon` in your example? How about `nheader`? You can simply slice the vector and _then_ reshape if the purpose of this loop is to skip the header. `A[nheader+1:].reshape((nlat, nlon))`. Could you add an example input and output to your question to make it clearer?

Comment: That might work. I'll give it a try and add an MRE if it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly and so much faster. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy`.

```py
import numpy as np

vector = np.array(A).reshape(nlat, nlon)
```