# Force array of arrays when using numpy genfromtext

Tags: python, numpy

Sample text input file:

```
35.6 45.1
21.2 34.1
30.3 29.3
```

When you use `numpy.genfromtxt(input_file, delimiter=' ')`, it loads the text file as an array of arrays

```
[[35.6 45.1]
 [21.2 34.1]
 [30.3 29.3]]
```

If there is only one entry or row of data in the input file, then it loads the input file as a 1d array
`[35.6 45.1]` instead of `[[35.6 45.1]]`

How do you force numpy to always result in a 2d array so that the resulting data structure stays consistent whether the input is 1 row or 10 rows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a 1D array to a 2D array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575421/convert-a-1d-array-to-a-2d-array-in-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ndmin` argument (new in 1.23.0):

```
numpy.genfromtxt(input_file, ndmin=2)
```

If you're on a version before 1.23.0, you'll have to do something else. If you don't have missing data, you can use `numpy.loadtxt`, which supports `ndmin` since 1.16.0:

```
numpy.loadtxt(input_file, ndmin=2)
```

Or if you know that your input will always have multiple columns, you can add the extra dimension with `numpy.atleast_2d`:

```
numpy.atleast_2d(numpy.genfromtxt(input_file))
```

(If you don't know how many rows *or* columns your input will have, it's impossible to distinguish the `genfromtxt` output for a single row or a single column, so `atleast_2d` won't help.)

Comment: Need to use numpy 1.17.3 and the second code block works. Thank you for writing solutions for multiple versions of numpy!