# How to convert a dataset column of numbers in python numpy 2D array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to ask for help. I have a dataset which has a column called pixels (I loaded with Pandas):

[image]

I would like to train this image classification dataset. So, I used split function inside apply pandas function

```
dfemotrain['pic']=dfemotrain['pixels'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x.split()).reshape(48, 48))
```

Later on, I used train_test_split from sklearn

```
X = dfemotrain['pic'].values
y = dfemotrain['emotion'].values
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, stratify=y, random_state=42)
print(X_train.shape, X_val.shape, y_train.shape, y_val.shape)
```

I got (21750,) (7250,) (21750,) (7250,) and I am not sure how to convert to a numpy array n_samplesx48x48 to input to a Deep Learning model

[image]

Please any suggestion to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you want to use reshape https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575421/convert-a-1d-array-to-a-2d-array-in-numpy

Comment: `X = np.array(dfemotrain['pic'].astype('int').to_list())`

Comment: `np.array(x.split(),dtype=int)` should turn those cell values into numeric arrays.  What did you `load` this from?  From a `csv`?  The frame cells contain strings, not lists or arrays.  Did you create the source file yourself, or get it from someone else?

Comment: I believe this question is not related to `scikit-learn` or `tensorflow`, therefore the tags are removed. Please try not to use irrelevant tags.

Comment: don't you have a data sample ?